# How can I specify remote destination server when using copy module in ansible

Tags: ansible, devops

##### Copying file to second server

Here is a task that I want to execute in order to copy dump file from prod server to test server.

How can I explicitly explicitly tell what the destination is? Or what's the correct approach.

I have already created a destination dir on the test server (/home/{{sys_user}}/prod_db_copy/).

Here is the task that I tried:

```
- name: "Copy dump file to test server"
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['prod']
  copy: 
    src: "/home/{{ sys_user }}/db_copy/{{ db_name }}.dump.gz"
    dest: "{{ inventory_hostname=='test' }} /home/{{sys_user}}/prod_db_copy/"
    remote_src: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`copy`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html) module copies files from the ansible controller to a remote machine or files on the remote machine, but what you are trying to do is copying files between two remote machines, so `copy` won't do the job. You need to use the [`synchronize`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-posix-synchronize-module) module with `delegate_to`.
Depending on your network and users on the machines, you might need to add some options or add ssh-keys to some servers, but in general, it can look like this:

```yaml
- hosts: prod
  tasks:
    - name: Transfer file from prod machines to backup-server
      synchronize:
        src: "/home/{{ sys_user }}/db_copy/{{ db_name }}.dump.gz"
        dest: "/home/{{sys_user}}/prod_db_copy/"
        mode: pull
      delegate_to: backup-server
```

This uses the `pull` mode. You can use `push` as well, but then you need to run the task on the `backup-server` and delegate it to the `prod` machine.

Comment: This is not very practical. 1) This will overwrite the same files from various hosts.  2) rsync must be installed both on the hosts and the backup server. 3) backup-server must be able to passwordless ssh connection to the hosts.

Comment: No. 1 is easily resolvable by adding the source hostname and a timestamp to the filename. No. 2 is not such a big issue, as `rsync` should be available and can easily be installed if not. No. 3 should be achievable using ssh-keys and you will always have that issue if you want to copy something between hosts directly. Otherwise you need to first download it to the controller and then upload it to another machine.